# Use DataFrame to reference values in a product key and add them all together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm creating an inventory management system with python.

When a customer places an order, I want to make sure the total weight of that order is under 1800g.

Say we have:

```
product_info = [{"mass_g": 700, "product_name": "apple", "product_id": 0}, {"mass_g": 700, "product_name": "banana", "product_id": 1}, {"mass_g": 750, "product_name": "grape", "product_id": 2}, {"mass_g": 680, "product_name": "pear", "product_id": 3}, {"mass_g": 350, "product_name": "orange", "product_id": 4}, {"mass_g": 200, "product_name": "flour", "product_id": 5}, {"mass_g": 120, "product_name": "brown_sugar", "product_id": 6}, {"mass_g": 80, "product_name": "arugula", "product_id": 7}, {"mass_g": 40, "product_name": "quinoa", "product_id": 8}, {"mass_g": 80, "product_name": "avocado", "product_id": 9}, {"mass_g": 300, "product_name": "syrup", "product_id": 10}, {"mass_g": 300, "product_name": "egg", "product_id": 11}, {"mass_g": 300, "product_name": "waffle", "product_id": 12}]
order = {"order_id": 123, "requested": [{"product_id": 0, "quantity": 2}, {"product_id": 10, "quantity": 4}]}
```

So far, I'm using DataFrame from the pandas module to get the ids and compare them   :

```
import pandas as pd

product_info_df = pd.DataFrame(product_info).set_index("product_id")
order_df = pd.DataFrame(order["requested"]).set_index("product_id")
order_weight = ???
if order_weight > 1800:
    print('This order is too heavy')
else:
    print('Product shipped!')
```

How do I take the order, look up each product's weight in product_info, multiply those by the order quantities, and add them all together to find total product weight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
order_weight = order_df.join(product_info_df)[['quantity', 'mass_g']].prod(1).sum()
print(order_weight)
```

**Output** *(order_weight)*

```
2600
```

The part `prod(1)` will multiply quantity and mass, and `.sum()` will sum all the resulting values from the multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

```
g=product_info_df.join(order_df).dropna()#Join and drop all NaNs to come up with an authentic order df
g.mass_g.mul(g.quantity).sum()#multiply quantity and mass.
```

Comment: @league edited my answer for some reason had converted to kg

Answer (score 0):

Could use:

```
order_df["weight"] = product_info_df.join(order_df, on="product_id", how='right')["mass_g"] * order_df["quantity"]
order_weight = order_df["weight"].sum()
```